# Obtener los valores de hora y minutos de un TimePickerDialog para usarlos en otro metodo

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un boton que al apretarlo se ejecuta este metodo:

```
  private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 int  h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();
                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
}, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Mi duda es simple: Como puedo utilizar los valores que se encuentran en `h` y `m` en otro método que esta en la misma clase. Como puedo "extraerlos", sacarlos de ese método?

Comment: Establece h y m como variables globales, o el método en el que los deseas utilizar puedes  recibirlos como parametros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya los estas extrayendo simplemente debes declarar que estos valores se almacenaran en variables de clase para que los uses en cualquier método de tu clase.

Define las variables debajo de la declaración de tu clase

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int m;
    private int h;
```

Ahora usa estas variables para almacenar los datos, de esta forma podrás usar los valores de `h` y `m`

```
  private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 //int  h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 //int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();

                 h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 m = view.getCurrentMinute();

                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
}, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

**es importante mencionar que estas variables tendrán valor de 0 hasta que tu abras el `TimePickerDialog` y selecciones un valor!**

Comment: Gracias, muy agradecido

Comment: excelente @Andry_UCI ,saludos!

Answer (score 1):

create dos variables de int privados dentro de tu clase, y los estableces desde ese metodo de la siguiente manera:

```
private int hora = 0;
private int minuto = 0;

private void mostrarHora(final TextView t) {
    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {
                 int  h= view.getCurrentHour();
                 int  m = view.getCurrentMinute();
                 minuto = view.getCurrentMinute();
                 hora = view.getCurrentHour();
                   setTxHora(h,m,t);
                }
}, h, m, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Selecciona la hora");
    timePickerDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: Gracias por tu SOLUCIÓN, ojala le pudiera aceptar las dos respuestas. Sinceramente GRACIAS